# Mysql exclude group if NULL value found in group

Tags: mysql

Considering this small sample set of data:

```
| id | territory_id | signed_in
| 1  | 6            | 2010-12-22 01:00:00
| 2  | 6            | 2011-12-11 01:00:00
| 3  | 6            | 2013-03-13 01:00:00
| 4  | 6            | NULL
| 5  | 3            | 2013-03-06 01:00:00
| 6  | 3            | 2013-11-20 01:00:00
```

I want to get results grouped by `territory_id` where the entire group does not contain a row where `signed_in` is `NULL`. Or basically I want to get these results:

```
| 5  | 3            | 2013-03-06 01:00:00
| 6  | 3            | 2013-11-20 01:00:00
```

This is my current sql which looks for the max `signed_in` value of each group while being joined to the `territories` table:

```
SELECT `territories`.`id`, `territories`.`label`, `territories`.`type_id`, `territories`.`area_type_id`, `territories`.`map_embed_id`, `tsio`.`signed_in`
FROM `territories` INNER JOIN (
    SELECT territory_id, MAX(signed_in) signed_in
    FROM `territories_sign_in_out`
    GROUP BY territory_id) tsio ON `territories`.`id` = `tsio`.`territory_id`
WHERE `territories`.`type_id` = ?
ORDER BY `tsio`.`signed_in` ASC 
LIMIT 15
```

Comment: *basically I want to get these results:*, so where territory_id = 3 ???

Comment: This is just a small data sample, I can't just select specific ids, rather I need all the results minus any groups that contain a NULL value on `signed_in`. Make more sense?

Comment: try sub query `WHERE territory_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT territory_id FROM territories_sign_in_out WHERE signed_in IS NULL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
select * from territories
where territory_id not in (
    select territory_id from territories where signed_in is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that should return the result you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM territories T
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT T2.territory_id
                 FROM territories T2
                 WHERE T2.signed_in IS NULL) TN ON TN.territory_id = T.territory_id
WHERE TN.territory_id IS NULL
```

Hope this will help you.